# Solr field not visible in query results

Tags: solr

I have added a new field in the schemas:

```
<field indexed="false" stored="true" docValues="true" sortMissingLast="true" name="RankScoreXXX" type="int" />
```

After all the indexing operations are done, in the solr admin panel while performing queries I do not see that field in any results where the value is actually 0. Results that contain a > 0 value in this specific field are shown.

By using this parameter I can see that none result does not contain this value
fq: -RankScoreXXX: [* TO *] .Also, I can sort results by this specific field.

I just do not understand why results with RankScoreXXX = 0 are not visible in the solr panel admin for given results.

Am I missing something?
Thanks.

Comment: This is no standard behavior. What is shown for http://localhost:8983/solr/[YourCore]/select?q=RankScoreXXX:0&wt=xml&fl=id,RankScoreXXX   ?

Comment: Are you sure you're actually indexing the field when it's 0?

Comment: Karsten, it does not show the field even accessing the direct url of the query. MatsLindh, I am going to double check it.

Comment: Data was corrupted, excuses for the question. I will try to close it. Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the datasets I was using to get these results where corrupted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have ran into this scenario a few times. Let me tell you what each one was:

1. Field was added but reindexing did not take place for all documents, only new ones. This is not your case as you reindexed.
2. Request handler was not updated in solrconfig.xml. In this case the person added the field and had configured the request handler to return a specific number of fields using fl. The field was not in the list.